# how to upload the image to folder using jquery

Tags: jquery

i need to copy the image to another folder using jquery .. please tell me how to do that .
 my html code

```
<form id="f1" name="form1" method="post">

                <div id="divdrag1" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" >
                    <ul type="none">
                        <li><img src="smiley.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="srcImg" id="drag1" width="45" height="45" align="left"> </li>
                        <li><img src="pic1.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="srcImg" id="drag2" width="45" height="45"> </li>
                        <li><img src="pic4.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="srcImg" id="drag3" width="45" height="45"> </li>
                        <li><img src="pic3.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="srcImg" id="drag4" width="45" height="45"> </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

                </div>
                <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='';">
                <button id="mybutton"  style="display:none;"></button>
                <input type="hidden" id="txtname" >
                <input type="button" name="btsubmit" id="btsubmit" value="AlertMe">
        </form>
```

My jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
                $('#btsubmit').click(function(){

                        var imagesrc = document.getElementById("ClonedElementX").src;
                        alert(imagesrc)
                });
            });
```

i dont know how to copy the image to folder . i got the source path .

please please help me

Comment: jQuery (and JavaScript) is client side. You need to use a server side language like PHP, Python, Perl, Ruby...

Comment: Use the 'copy' function in php..Google search should answer your question.

Comment: you need to store it on server side , client side wont help :( :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to use server side scripting. Better use PHP

May be this can help you

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_move_uploaded_file.asp